# GLSL Interlacing

Tags: c++, optimization, opengl, glsl, interlacing

I would like to efficiently render in an interlaced mode using GLSL.

I can alrdy do this like:

```
vec4 background = texture2D(plane[5], gl_TexCoord[1].st);
if(is_even_row(gl_TexCoord[1].t))
{
    vec4 foreground = get_my_color();
    gl_FragColor = vec4(fore.rgb * foreground .a + background .rgb * (1.0-foreground .a), background .a + fore.a);
}
else
   gl_FragColor = background;
```

However, as far as I have understood the nature of branching in GLSL is that both branches will actually be executed, since "even_row" is considered as run-time value.

Is there any trick I can use here in order to avoid unnecessarily calling the rather heavy function "get_color"? The behavior of is_even_row is quite static.

Or is there some other way to do this?

NOTE: glPolygonStipple will not work since I have custom blend functions in my GLSL code.

Comment: Unless you are running on a software renderer, I would _strongly_ discourage you from rendering in interlaced mode. It will look worse, but it will not be any faster. In fact, it may very well be slower. Interlaced rendering interferes with a GPU's natural 2x2 block shading, which is no good.

Comment: I'm compositing and interlacing video and later in the pipeline displaying on a tv running in 1080i. It must be interlaced.

Comment: In that case, how about doing everything with 1/2 the Y resolution, and drawing a textured fullscreen quad as the last thing, and abusing the stencil buffer to mask out the odd lines? This way, at least all but the very last pass are GPU-friendly. Alternatively, one could do "explicit Z culling", if stencil is not available.

Comment: If you post your comment as an answer I could accept it. How does a stencil buffer mask compare to gl PolygonStipple?

Comment: One note: Use mix function for this: fore.rgb * foreground .a + background .rgb * (1.0-foreground .a)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(comment to answer, as requested)

The problem with interlacing is that GPUs run shaders in 2x2 clusters, which means that you gain nothing from interlacing (a good software implementation might possibly only execute the actual pixels that are needed, unless you ask for partial derivatives).

At best, interlacing runs at the same speed, at worst it runs slower because of the extra work for the interlacing. Some years ago, there was an article in ShaderX4, which suggested interlaced rendering. I tried that method on half a dozen graphics cards (3 generations of hardware of each the "two big" manufacturers), and it ran slower (sometimes slightly, sometimes up to 50%) in every case.

What you could do is do all the expensive rendering in 1/2 the vertical resolution, this will reduce the pixel shader work (and texture bandwidth) by 1/2. You can then upscale the texture (GL_NEAREST), and discard every other line.

The stencil test can be used to discard pixels before the pixel shader is executed. Of course the hardware still runs shaders in 2x2 groups, so in this pass you do not gain anything. However, that does not matter if it's just the very last pass, which is a trivial shader writing out a single fetched texel. The more costly composition shaders (the ones that matter!) run at half resolution.
You find a detailled description including code here: [fake dynamic branching](http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=3D&ID=50). This demo avoids lighting pixels by discarding those that are outside the light's range using the stencil.

Another way which does not need the stencil buffer is to use "explicit Z culling". This may in fact be even easier and faster.
For this, clear Z, disable color writes (`glColorMask`), and draw a fullscreen quad whose vertices have some "close" Z coordinate, and have the shader kill fragments in every odd line (or use the deprecated alpha test if you want, or whatever). `gl_FragCoord.y` is a very simple way of knowing which line to kill, using a small texture that wraps around would be another (if you must use GLSL 1.0).
Now draw another fullscreen quad with "far away" Z values in the vertices (and with depth test, of course). Simply fetch your half-res texture (GL_NEAREST filtering), and write it out. Since the depth buffer has a value that is "closer" in every other row, it will discard those pixels.

How does `glPolygonStipple` compare to this? Polygon stipple is a deprecated feature, because it is not directly supported by the hardware and has to be emulated by the driver either by "secretly" rewriting the shader to include extra logic or by falling back to software.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the right way to do interlacing.  If you really need to achieve this effect, don't do it in the fragment shader like this.  Instead, here is what you could do:

1. Initialize a full screen 1-bit stencil buffer, where each bit stores the parity of its corresponding row.
2. Render your scene like usual to a temporary FBO with 1/2 the vertical resoltion.
3. Turn on the stencil test, and switch the stencil func depending on which set of scan lines you are going to draw.
4. Blit a rescaled version of the aforementioned fbo (containing the contents of your frame) to the stencil buffer.

Note that you could skip the offscreen FBO step and draw directly using the stencil buffer, but this would waste some fill rate testing those pixels that are just going to clipped anyway.  If your program is shader heavy, the solution I just mentioned would be optimal.  If it is not, you may end up being *marginally* better off drawing directly to the screen.